# Ordering of DELETE and UPDATE statements in Entity Framework Core generated SQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following objects, which exist as entities in my DbContext connected to a PostgreSQL database:

```cs
public class Absence
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AbsenceReason AbsenceReason { get; set; }
}
```

---

```cs
public class AbsenceReason
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public List<Absence> Absences { get; set; }
}
```

Each object is obviously larger, I've edited them to include only what I think are the relevant parts. Our requirements include that absences reasons can be soft deleted while still being attached to existing absences. Absence reasons should be hard deleted if there are no absences left that refer to them.

This works fine when I delete the last absence that referenced a soft deleted absence reason. However, I have issues when an absence is updated to no longer reference a soft deleted absence reason.

From my controller, on the same context I run:

```cs
DbSet.Remove(absenceReason);
DbSet.Update(absence);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It does not matter in what order the remove and update lines of code run. I've double-checked that fact, and everything I've read tells me that EF chooses the order SQL instructions should be run by itself. The problem is that the generated SQL is obviously not going to work:

```sql
DELETE FROM "AbsenceReasons"
WHERE "Id" = @p0;
UPDATE "Absences" SET "AbsenceReasonId" = @p1
WHERE "Id" = @p10;
```

EF decides the right thing to do is to try deleting the absence reason first before updating the absence to no longer refer to the absence reason. The result is that a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException gets raised.

How can I resolve this while maintaining atomicity?

Note: Using EF Core 5.0.1

Comment: Does it matter about atomicity for this? If no, why not do an update save remove save

Comment: @CaiusJard I understand that would work, but I don't want to sacrifice atomicity for something that should be relatively simple to accomplish, just in case there's a problem down the road.

Comment: @NicholasVerstegen `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes using an internal transaction.  The problem here is the controller code, not how EF Core orders the changes. The generated SQL will work just fine. The `UPDATE` won't modify anything. It's the controller code that requested that order - a `DELETE` followed by an `UPDATE`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I specified in the question I have tested this and the order in the controller does not matter. Doing `DbSet.Update(absence);` first and `DbSet.Remove(absenceReason);` second gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using TransactionScope to force the correct order and maintain atomicity.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    DbSet.Update(absence);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    DbSet.Remove(absenceReason);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    scope.Complete();
}
```